# indy https GET - authentication

Tags: delphi, authentication, https, delphi-7, indy

I am trying to make a HTTPS-get request work in order to load a webpage wich has the url starting with "https:". I am using Indy10 (5248) with delphi 7. I don't seem to be able to get the authorization right, even using the same name/password or domain\name/password that I use in a browser. All I get is the same server response as if in the browser I would cancel the authentication request.

Now there are several ways to supply name/pwd:

- they can be entered as property values in idHTTP.request
- idem, in idHTTP.ProxyParams
- idHTTP has a number of on...Authorization-events
- a [Post-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223839/how-to-make-an-https-post-request-in-delphi) uses named parameters, but that seems to be specific for the google site it is trying to access (otherwise, how would I find out what the parameter names are..?)

In addition there are options. Even though there's a finite number of combinations, I haven't been able yet to find one working for me. What is the correct way of doing this?

```
s := IdHTTP1.Get('https://qwerty.wur.nl');
Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Response Code: %d', [IdHTTP1.ResponseCode]));
Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Response Text: %s', [IdHTTP1.ResponseText]));

Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need proxy params. Set `IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication` instead:

```
IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication:= true;
IdHTTP1.Request.UserName := UserName;
IdHTTP1.Request.Password := Password;
```

Be aware that you need to prepare your application and `IdHTTP1` for SSL as explained here: [Delphi: idHttp+SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683127/delphi-idhttpssl) and here [TIdHTTP.Get EIdIOHandlerPropInvalid Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554003/tidhttp-get-eidiohandlerpropinvalid-error)

Comment: So, your suggestion is authentication through the Request. There must be something else to it too, for this is one of the variants I have tried (and rechecked now, with a 'fresh' idHTTP component).
I think missing dlls make themselves known in a less ambiguous way (Could not load SSL library.).

Comment: When you have HTTP authentication then you need to do it via `IdHTTP1.Request`. What kind of authentication do you have? What is the response that you receive? ResponseCode, ResponsMessage?

Comment: 1. `BasicAuthentication=true` is not always the correct thing to use. It merely tells `TIdHTTP` that it can use `BASIC` authentication if no other authentication has been specified. Not all servers support `BASIC` as it is not secure. 2. See [New HTTPS functionality for TIdHTTP](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20141222.aspx).

Comment: The response is "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials". I do not understand the question: What kind of authentication do you have? I have provided name and pwd to the request as suggested here, having BasicAuthentication alternating true and false.

Comment: If there is no object assigned to the `TIdHTTP.Request.Authentication` property, and `TIdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication` is true, `TIdHTTP` will assign a default `TIdBasicAuthentication` object to the `Authentication` property. If `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` is triggered, the `Authentication` property is assigned a new object of the selected `AuthenticationClass`. So, it is the `Authentication` object that decides which auth scheme to use to send credentials to the server in the HTTP `Authentication` header. It sounds like the server does not accept `BASIC` authentication.

Comment: No, alas, after a lot of trying, I am giving up. It should be possible though, with NTLM-authentication ipWorks can do it. A code example might help.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to specify HTTP authentication credentials in `TIdHTTP` is to use the `TIdHTTP.Request` properties.  That is where `TIdHTTP` looks for them when starting a new authenticated session.  If the server rejects/challenges the authentication, the `OnSelectAuthorization` and `OnAuthorization` events are triggered to allow the app to select a different authentication scheme and/or supply different credentials, respectively.

As for the [POST example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223839/), it is posting an HTML webform, such as you would see on a website's login page.  The parameters are determined by analyzing the HTML that defines the webform, just like a webbrowser would do.  Webform authentication has nothing to do with HTTP authentication.  The two are not mutually exclusive, they can be used together if the server decides to.

Comment: Thanks for confirmig what I suspected about the post-example. However: the server rejects the authentication it receives but neither OnSelectAuthorization nor OnAuthorization fires when BasicAuthentication is True; OnSelectAuthentication fires though when BasicAuthentication is False - should I react on that event? (AuthenticationClass is TIdSSPINTLMAuthentication).

Comment: `On(Select)Authorization` is triggered when the server returns a 401 response, which presents the client with available auth schemes and challenge data so it can retry the request with a new/updated `Authentication` header. If the server returns a 403 response, authentication failed. So, it sounds like the server is returning 403 when `BasicAuthentication` is true. In `OnSelectAuthorization`, `AuthenticationClass` is initialized with Indy's selection based on available auth classes, but you can overwrite it with another auth class, as long as its scheme is listed in the `AuthInfo` parameter.